# Post-запрос в яндекс-танк

Tags: яндекс-танк

Как правильно создать post-запрос с картинкой для яндекс-танка. Нужно картинку в binary data конвертировать? И я правильно понял что помимо load.ini нужно создавать отдельный файл с заголовком запроса и телом?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется [это](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=post#uri-post-style) должно работать. Там пункт "sample POST requests (binary data)". Дополнительные файлы скорее всего придется создать.